# Not returning JSON data correctly

Tags: javascript, php, json

Hey I don't use PHP very often maybe once a year and I am having a lot of trouble returning data correctly. Basically I am getting an object that seems to contain  my data in the response text which I don't know why. If someone could explain to me why this happens I'd be very grateful!

[image]

this is the code from the back end

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']){
        case'getCandidates' :
        {
            $bus = array(
                'latitude' => $row['lat'],
                'longitude' => $row['lng'],
                'icon' => './images/' . $row['busColor'] . '.png'
            );
            array_push($json, $bus);
            $query = "SELECT * from candidates WHERE  status = '$status' AND category = '$category' AND location = '$location'";
            $returnRows = $db->con->query($query);
            if ($returnRows->num_rows > 0) {
                $x = 0;
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $returnRows->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $object = new stdClass();
                    $object->status = $row["status"];
                    $object->first_name = $row["first_name"];
                    $object->last_name = $row["last_name"];
                    $object->category = $row["category"];

                    array_push($aResult, $object);

                }
            } else {
                $aResult[0] = "No results";
            }

//                $aResult['result']  = mysql_fetch_object($returnRows);;
            }
```

and this is the front end code

```
returnedCandidates = $.ajax({
    url: "../php/admin.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {action: 'getCandidates'},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        alert(data);
    }});
console.log(JSON.parse(returnedCandidates[0]));
```

and this is the line for returning data with php. I forgot to add it.

print_r(json_encode ($aResult));

Comment: sorry I am using print_r to return

Comment: Dont! Instead use `echo json_encode($aResult);` [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: What is temp1? Is it `data`? If not what's returned in data?

Answer (score 0):

comment line:

```
//print_r(json_encode ($aResult));
```

and return like this:

```
return (json_encode ($aResult));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use print_r for return.

Try this code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($aResult);
```

Comment: Nope no luck this is really bugging me. I usually work in c# so Php is a little perplexing right now

Comment: There is no way that this code can't work ;) I mean that nobody won't give you better answer without knowledge of context of code you've shown us.

Comment: I dunno. I actually had this in but the print r wasn't echo and all it's doing is returning the data in responsetext..... That's now what I need. Honestly it's a bit of a head scratcher to me.